# Computing checksum for data packets of Midi Sample Dump Standard

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, midi, bitwise-operators

I am trying to write an open source implementation of the Midi Sample Dump Standard, and am having a hard time understanding why the checksum I'm computing for each data packet coming from the device I'm testing with does not match the checksum the device is sending.
The code I've written is [here](https://gist.github.com/briansorahan/6967891), and there is good info about the SDS spec [here](http://www.blitter.com/~russtopia/MIDI/~jglatt/tech/sds.htm). Hopefully someone who has more experience using bitwise operators can find what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: At first glance, your code matches what the checksum description asks for. Can you give us the full packets and checksums to check against?

Comment: Most MIDI protocols use not XOR but addition for checksums; SDS might not be an exception.

Answer (score 1):

The 5 years that have elapsed since this question was asked are but a flicker in the lifetime of the venerable MIDI sample dump standard. For other seekers of this arcane knowledge, I will present an answer here.
A MIDI sample dump message contains a header of 21 bytes and a variable number of sample data packets of 127 bytes each (let's call them 0 to 126). Each of the data packets has a checksum at byte number 125. It is computed by successively xoring each byte in the packet from byte number 1 to byte 124 inclusive. The result is then anded with 0x7F (to zero out the status bit). Here is the relevant code lifted from "sds.c" in libsndfile. Note that this code also verifies that byte 1 is 0x7E which indicates that this is a sample dump message.

```
checksum = psds->read_data [1] ;
if (checksum != 0x7E)                      
{   printf ("Error 1 : %02X\n", checksum & 0xFF) ;
    }

for (k = 2 ; k <= SDS_BLOCK_SIZE - 3 ; k ++)
    checksum ^= psds->read_data [k] ;

checksum &= 0x7F ;
```